# Using Weights Column in H2O random forest and xgboost

Tags: random-forest, h2o, xgboost

I am trying to maximize precision in a binary classification problem (there is a high cost to false positives). The data set is really unbalanced as well. Would it make sense to run a DRF or XGBOOST model twice, using the weights column the second time in order to counter-act false positives?

Are there other methods within these H2O algorithms to maximize precision (rather than log-loss) besides this potential method? I am also going to use an ensemble (which does seems to increase precision). Cross-validation does not appear to help.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would use `balance_classes` (set it to true). That will help, a bit, with unbalanced data. (Also look at `class_sampling_factors` and `max_after_balance_size` if you need to take fine control.)

My hunch would be that your suggestion to use the output of one model to weight a second model is dangerous. It sounds like a bit of the idea of stacked ensemble, but hand-coded and custom code is more likely to have bugs. (But, if you do try it, it would be interesting to see the code and the results.)

To maximize precision I'd go with an ensemble, and put my effort into making 3 or 4 models that have different strengths and weaknesses. E.g. a GBM, a GLM, a deep learning model with all defaults, then a deep learning model using dropout (and more hidden nodes, to compensate).

Comment: Should be an idea to insert weights using the *weights_column*? For example, the positive examples should have an higher weight w.r.t the negative ones, in order to put the focus on the true positive.